# current approaches for designing image heavy photo sites?

Tags: lightbox, photo, portfolio

I have just come back to web design after almost 10 years .. things have changed.

After some research I can see that old school html pagination has gone and CSS div based responsive apps have replaced it.

My initial researches have shown that I will probably need to approach this using:

- extensive use of CSS/JQuery/JS
- responsive cross platform design
- self contained object/module/app based design with much reduced html
  pagination
- Some form of lazy loading (in the absence of pagination)
- serverside globbing to return JSON folder contents

Are there any other key techniques/technologies I should get my head around, because its hurting already just working out div layouts ..

to clarify .. I am from the `<a href=photo_detail.php?id=123><img ..></a>` generation  :)

I have made a start here - [Paul Walsh](http://fworld.net/paulwalsh.html)

I am considering using a paid service like Photoshelter - but my first reaction is they are actually too CSS heavy, and not sufficiently customisable .. on the other hand the back end photo upload/management app is very useful and a lot of work to create just for my own site, so I would have to do all this at OS/directory level with manual resizing , thumbnail generation etc.

Comment: Lightbox or fancybox are two helps that should be checked out, fancybox is very good. and yes, everything is simple HTML and a multitude of possibly-complex CSS. Edit: As in, louad small thumbnails onto the page and then display the full size images with lightbox or fancybox popups.

Comment: are these JQuery classes or JS scripts?

Comment: They are JQuery - (JQuery is an extension of Javascript), a quick Google on both and they'll be easily found.

Comment: thanks - I do not want to re-invent the wheel so I think a simple site with JQuery plugins seems the way to go otherwise I am get caught out on browser / platform compatibility I think. Also probably something like Dropbox or Flickr API for management, delivery and storage. Thanks.

Comment: I think the most important thing after 10 year gap is to get onboard with `<div>` and avoid tables for layout. I know this route is older than 10 years probably but worth reminding, that tables are just for tabular data. Also check out HTML5 as the new up and coming version, as well as  checking out things like site specific meta tags such as OpenGraph [link](http://ogp.me/) and MicroData [link](http://schema.org). Good luck :)

Comment: CSS is great - but the div based DOM must be the most unintuitive thing I have ever come across - give me Perl anyday ... Martin thanks for the advice ..

Comment: Divs are just holders for CSS rules, the action is all in the CSS.....